# How to convert a (javascript) date to the API timestamp format?

Tags: support, api-v2, javascript

When I am using [this page for the Stack Exchange API `/search` path](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search), I can see that it is generating time-stamps in this format:

```
fromdate=1380326400&todate=1380412800
```

What is this date format? How do I convert, to this time stamp, from

```
var date = new Date().getTime();
```

??

I got the specification from [this doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates) , but I didn't get any method to convert, it is not just eliminating the millisecond values by dividing by 1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `.getTime()` value is already in UTC, you can just divide by 1000, *and round*.

That is:

```js
var apiDate = Math.round (new Date().getTime() / 1000);
```

works just fine.

`apiDate` is in ["unix epoch time"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and the API takes these values even if the API parameter is called a "Date".

---

But, if you want **to truncate to the date only**, just use:

```js
var dateTime = new Date ();
dateTime.setUTCHours   (0);
dateTime.setUTCMinutes (0);
dateTime.setUTCSeconds (0);

var apiDate = Math.round (dateTime.getTime() / 1000);
```

---

---

See, also "[How do I parse the dates from the API?](https://stackapps.com/q/4182/7653)".

Comment: I cant double like :)