# How to get the user's last seen time in user's profile

Tags: support, api, users

In user's profile page, there's a `last seen xx mins ago` info:

[image: user profile, partial screenshot]

How can I get this information in [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) object or other object field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's "Last seen" time is the `last_access_date` property of [the API's `user` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user).  Get it via a call to [the `/users/{ids}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids).
For example:
    [/2.2/users/50274?site=stackapps](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/50274?site=stackapps)

Which currently shows your `last_access_date` as `1528358274`.

In the API, [dates are in unix epoch time](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates), so `1528358274` corresponds to *Thu, 07 Jun 2018 07:57:54 GMT*.

For more information about converting dates/times, see [How do I parse the dates from the API?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4182/how-do-i-parse-the-dates-from-the-api).